# Substitute text on keypress

Tags: android, android-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

I would like to improve my productivity by creating some shortcuts

For example, when I type :

```
toast(var)
```

and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, it substitutes with :

```
Toast.makeText(this, var, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

And a few others of the same kind. Is there a way to do this in IntelliJ/Android Studio?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use **Live Templates**.

If you go to **Settings > Live Templates** then you will be provided with a list of groups and templates within them. If you right click on the pane and select **Move > New group...** then you can create a group to store your own custom templates.

Once you have created a group, select it and click the little green plus sign in the top right and choose **Live Template**. This will create a new template in your custom group.

In the **Abbreviation** box put `toast` and you can leave the description blank. Then in the **Template text** box put `Toast.makeText(this, $var$, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`. The final step is to click the **Define** link below and select **Java**.

Now to test it out. What this will do is when you type the abbreviation text, in our case `toast`, in a `.java` file and press tab(by default) then it will write out what we added to the **Template text** box. Then it will place the cursor at the `$var$` position in the text.

You can follow this routine for other kinds of templates that you may wish to do. I would recommend having one for logging to logcat.